# Fedex Developer Rest API Ship API

Tags: fedex

I am trying to play around with FedEx APIs: https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/home.html
and actually I would like to know, is it possible to track new created Shipment via Ship API on sandbox/test environment?

Actually I've tried to create multiple different types of Shipments validate them, and received 200 Ok response, however I wasn't able to track it by tracking number returned in response, so the question is it possible at all on API sandbox environment to create Shipment and find it by tracking number on FedEx site or using Track API's Track by Number Endpoint.

Cannot find such limitations in documentation, so will be very appreciated if someone can shed light on this.

Comment: I used the package **JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper**, the example for creating an openshipment is: https://github.com/JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/blob/master/examples/create-open-shipment.php

Comment: And you can track such shipment by Tracking Number returned in response?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to track with the tracking IDs which you get from ship API.

But you can track the orders with the mock tracking numbers [from here.](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/guides/api-reference.html#mocktrackingnumbersforfedexexpressandfedexground)

It's really very irritating because when we get the tracking IDs in the test environment, we should be able to track the orders by using them in the test environment. FedEx should have to focus on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for your request body/content and make sure you have a valid Oauth token (which you can get here https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token): :

```
{
    "includeDetailedScans": true,
    "trackingInfo": [
        {
            "trackingNumberInfo": {
                "trackingNumber": "509466710003247",
                "carrierCode": "FDXG",
                "trackingNumberUniqueId": "245822~123456789012~FDEG"
            },
            "shipDateBegin": "2020-03-29",
            "shipDateEnd": "2024-04-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above will fetch a valid tracking number; your response will look like the following:

[image]

Let me know if you have any more issues; I am happy to assist.